# Issue in calling a function using string literals(template literals) when click on a button

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-literals, template-literals

So basically I want to call a function with a parameter when I click a button. And the button is created using a string literal.

```
  function showNewUserOnScreen(user) {
    let parentNode = document.getElementById("listOfUser");
    let childhtml = `<li> ${user.username} - ${user.email}
                            <button onclick = ${() => deleteUser(user.email)}> Delete </button>
                    </li>`;

    parentNode.innerHTML = parentNode.innerHTML + childhtml;
  }
```

The above image is the code that I have written, and now would like you to look at the below image of how the code gets its output in the browser.

[image]

This second image is what I get in the browser. Now when I click on this delete button it gives me the error as shown in the below image

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' (at localstorage.html:1:2)
```

Comment: Please  post code and error messages as text.

Comment: replaced code images to text and similarly error messages to text

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work in the way you think it does (or should). Template literals will evaluate the contents of the expressions you enclose in `${}`, so an expression representing a function definition won't evaluate to much of anything useful in this context.

If you're intent on using inline `on*` parameters and generating DOM elements from HTML strings (both no longer recommended practices in favor of using `addEventListener()` and `createElement()`/`appendChild()` (and other DOM manipulation methods), respectively), just include the name of the function you want to run on that event and use the template literal portion to pass just the string argument:

```
let childhtml = `<li> ${user.username} - ${user.email}
                        <button onclick="deleteUser('${user.email}')"> Delete </button>
                </li>`;
```

This will lead to issues (including security issues) down the road if `user.email` can contain apostrophes (`'` or `"`); as such I would recommend switching to the more modern syntaxes I mentioned above (among other reasons).

Comment: I tried this, but now when I click on the delete button it give me error as:
```
localstorage.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteUser is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (localstorage.html:1:1)
```

Comment: @Manan: Yeah, as this answer points out that's not a good practice anyway. Create your elements with `createElement()`, `appendChild()`, and `addEventListener()`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, Ok I understand, but is there no other way to call deleteUser function directly from string literals as I did instead of using '''createElement()''', '''appendChild()''' or ```addEventListener()```??

Comment: Do you not have a `deleteUser` function defined? What are you trying to call?

Comment: @esqew, Yes I have deleteUser function defined but when I click on that button, i need to pass user email as a parameter..............so when i click, it gives me error deleteUser is not defined

Comment: I would posit that’s a whole other question altogether - it seems that the initial generation of the `onclick` value you’re after is solved. Contrary to your implication, you *are* passing the user email as a parameter with this code (it’s being interpolated into the string as a parameter to `deleteUser`) - the interpreter is telling you that the function `deleteUser` doesn’t exist to begin with.

Comment: @Manan: the javascript expression in the click handler gets invoked in a global scope, so if `deleteUser` is defined at that high level then this answer should work. You can test that by opening your web browser's debugging tools console and typing `deleteUser`: if you see your function, then it's in the global scope. But if your app grows you'll want to organize your app's code into components rather than having all the things sitting on the `window` object.

Comment: After you've tried doing all of this with vanilla HTML and JavaScript, it gives you a real appreciation for frameworks like React, Vue, and Angular--they let you use a simple templating language to render DOM and tie it to the model and component code pretty seamlessly.